# Uploading Files To Web Server Without Using FTP - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, web, ftp

My application stores data in a database and I want to be able to create a remote backup. However, my client's network blocks FTP.

I know there must be a way to upload files to a server without FTP as the Dropbox application works fine on their system, I'm just unsure as to what this method is. I've tried google but haven't had much success.

Hopefully someone out there can help me.

Thanks in advance,
Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a PHP script on the server to move the file and in VB.Net just upload it

```
My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("local path","remote location")
```

then the PHP side

```
<?php if (!empty($_FILES["file"])){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images‌​/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
?>
```

Comment: Note that PHP has limits on PUT/POST operations.

Comment: @bensonsearch Thanks for your response. I am not quite sure what you are suggesting. What I want to do is to upload the whole file to a directory on the server rather than individual pieces of data into a database, which is what I think you are suggesting above. Thanks again, Craig.

Comment: @CraigBlackie my appologies yes this is for individual data, look into My.Computer.Network.UploadFile("local path","remote location") again use a php script to catch the file and move it

Comment: eg <?php if (!empty($_FILES["file"])){move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);?>

Comment: @bensonsearch Okay thanks. I will try this out as soon as I get back to my machine later on.

Comment: @bensonsearch Brilliant! Works perfectly, thank you very much. Can you update your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

I use Remote Desktop Connection to move files back and forth.
This works if your server is a windows box.

Comment: Hi @ScottSavage, thanks for your help. Unfortunately my server isn't a Windows machine.